# Getting prohibited sign with apple logo on start up of Macbook pro 2012 non-retina

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

Background:
My macbook pro start to become unpredictable in beginning, sometime really slow, unusable slow and sometimes it starts work normally.
I tried first aid from SSD but nothing wrong.
After few days I started to get folder sign with question mark, not always.
After couple days more, I got prohibited sign, but prohibited sign is not consistent on screen, after 8-9 seconds I see apple logo for second again prohibited sign for 8-9. And repeat.
Can it be something related to cable connecting SSD or SSD itself.
While trying to reinstall OS X, installed couldn't find any drive either.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, though unlikely, that the SSD itself may be failing. The SATA connector is a much more likely source of failure, and commonly occurs in those Unibody models. Replacements can be found on eBay cheaply, though make sure you get the right part for your model, as they vary in length.

You can also get a USB to SATA cable cheaply, so you can test the drive as an external, to see if it works there.

Comment: Tried new SATA connector, no improvement.
Installed Black magic disk speed test and found read speed I am getting is only .2 MB. Write speed is above 400 mb./s. 
Formatted SSD and installed OSX again 10.8. Still very slow. 
Upgraded to Catalina, still slow. But after two suddenly become normal. Not sure how long it gonna last.